# MongoDB - How to use JavaScript variable in expression?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do you put a variable inside this expression? I tried

```
var myVariable = 'something';

db.test.find({$where: "myVariable.match( ... )"});
```

but I get an error "myVariable is not defined". What's the way to do this?

Comment: I tried what you have just posted. Didn't get any error.
Can you elaborate more?

Comment: If you want to do this you will need to use $eval to put the variable in the scope of the function

Comment: Note: use of [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is generally discouraged as JavaScript evaluation cannot take advantage of indexes. If you can include an example of a sample document and actual query you're trying to construct, there is likely a more performant alternative to recommend.

Comment: @stennie I'm not sure there is. `{$where: "myVariable.match(new RegExp(this.test + '$'))"}`. If `myVariable = 'something'`, it should get documents that match the end substring, e.g., `mething`, `thing`, `ing`.

Comment: you can use [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: @Michael I don't see how in this case, `{'test': {$regex: ??? }}`. The input `something` is bigger than `mething`, `thing`, `ing`, etc.

Comment: The code you listed `myVariable.match(new RegExp(this.test + '$'))` will not work the way you think since it is basically `$regex`, both use the same searching method and abilities

Comment: @Sammaye It's not possible with just $regex. Go ahead and try. But it's getting off topic, I only want to know how to access the variable, that's my question.

Comment: `$regex: {"pattern": "/mething|thing|ing/"}` done

Comment: @Sammaye That's not even remotely the same concept... the whole point is that it's dynamic, without knowing ahead of time... what you have there is fixed. In that case I would just use the $in operator, why use regex at all.

Comment: But you can put your own content into the regex operator, I don't see what the difference is between regex and the JS regex object, both use the same process to search documents

Comment: @sammaye $regex compares a field against a pattern. But that regex object  appends `$` to each field value instead.

Comment: But in regex $ is a reserved character meaning end of line as such it is actually twisting your regex beyound what you expect

Comment: That's what I mean I still don't understand since you can do that without the need for $where as well.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding because my original question was about how to access a variable in the expression. That example was made for that question.  `myVariable` isn't a fixed value, it's dynamic and unknown. So if it happens to be `friedchicken` then it should get documents with a field `test` whose value is a substring of `friedchicken`, matching from the end. E.g., `{'test': 'friedchicken'}`, `{'test': 'edchicken'}`, `{'test': 'chicken'}`, `{'test': 'ken'}`, etc. But not `{'test': 'fried'}`.

Comment: Imagine in PHP `db.c.find(['text' => new \MongoRegex($text . '$')])` same is just done

Answer (score 2):

You need your variable to be in the local scoop of `$where` like this:

```js
db.test.find({ "$where": function(){
    var myVariable = "something";
    return myVariable.match( ... )
    }
);
```